# SSIS Column Combining

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to combine data from multiple excel columns into one column and want to avoid copying and pasting it manually over and over each time I receive a file.

The data will come in this format:

```
C1    C2     C3     Date1  Date2  Date3 ... DateN
text  text2  text3   ###    ###    ###       ###
text  text2  text3   ###    ###    ###       ###
```

The end goal is to have all the dates in a column by themselves and to have all the values in a column next to their respective dates to load into a MSS table like so:

```
C1    C2     C3      Results  Date
text  text2  text3   ###      Date1
text  text2  text3   ###      Date1
text  text2  text3   ###      Date2
text  text2  text3   ###      Date2
text  text2  text3   ###      Date3
text  text2  text3   ###      Date3
```

So far I'm drawing a blank on what could be done to automate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SSIS Unpivot Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx); it does exactly what you need. The only caveat - number of **Date** columns has to be fixed before you design and run SSIS package; you cannot handle dynamic number of columns in SSIS with builtin transformations.

Comment: This looks pretty promising.  Do you know if there is any way to write a script component that could account for the number of columns or is finding out the quantity beforehand the only way?

Comment: @Bigby, that is a cornerstone. SSIS has to know and set in package data layout (metadata), including column name, format etc, **before** it executes. Moreover, SSIS validates match between metadata and real situation at package start, and fires error if not matching.  
If you really want to handle variable number of columns - get data from table with `select * from ...` statement and put into an Object variable, and process it in Script task.